# Error in If else condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below codeigniter code i have placed the controller if i type invalid username or passwors it displays inactive user please contact admin but i want to display invalisd username or password .Pls help me to solve the issue.

controller:

```
function inactive()
    {
    echo"<script>alert('In active user Please contact the administrator');</script>";
    $this->load->view('login_form'); 
    }
    function invalid()
    {
    echo"<script>alert('Invalid username or password');</script>";
    $this->load->view('login_form'); 
    }
    function validate_credentials()
    {       
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            if($query->num_rows()>0){
             $status = $query->row()->account_status;}
            else {
             $status = ''; }
            if($status == 'active')
            {
               $this->session->set_userdata($data);
               redirect('site1/members_area');
            }
            else //Account In active
            {  $this->inactive();  }
        }
        else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->invalid();
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to echo $status = $query->row()->account_status; then view the value

Comment: i placed the code in the place of $this->inactive(); when i log as a in active user it display inactive and for invalid username it displays  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: print_r($query->num_rows());

Comment: i placed the code in the place of $this->inactive(); when it is inactive user it displays 1 and invalid username it displays 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this code :

```
function validate_credentials()
{       
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            $status = $query->row()->account_status;
            if($status == 'active')
            {
               $this->session->set_userdata($data);
               redirect('site1/members_area');
            }
            else //Account In active
            {  $this->inactive();  }
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->invalid();
        }

    }
    else // incorrect username or password
    {
        $this->invalid();
    }
}
```

if you still have trouble show me the query then i can help you.